# How to specify a specific path of dll for executable?

Tags: qt, dll, executable

i have made one executable in qt. It runs perfectly fine on my computer but when i try to run it on another computer, it gives error. I think my exe is not able to load dll's from System32 folder. Is there any way i can set path in my exe so that it looks for any missing dll's in windows System32 folder which are not in the  folder in which executable and other dll's are present. Thanks

Comment: Put the required dlls in the same folder as the executable. ***Is there any way i can set path in my exe so that it looks for any missing dll's in windows System32 folder*** Windows will do that already.

Comment: Here is some information about how windows looks for your dlls; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Don't "think" about what DLLs your application is trying to load, go get Dependency Walker and find out for certain.

Comment: I have copied all the libraries as shown in dependency walker but the executable is still showing some dll error in another system. Most probably the dll missing is from system32 folder. Is there any way through which I can give a path to the executable so that it automatically checks out the system32 folder for missing libraries?

Comment: ***Ag I can give a path to the executable so that it automatically checks out the system32 folder for missing libraries?*** Again windows already looks in system32 for dlls if they are not found in the same folder as the executable. This is not the issue.

Comment: So, why it is not able to locate dll's from system32 folder? I mean what makes the difference between my system32 dll's and another system32 dll's?